# How do I subset a pandas dataframe based on a list of column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split, typeerror

I have a client data df with 200+ columns, say A,B,C,D...X,Y,Z. There's a column in this df which has CAMPAIGN_ID in it. I have another data mapping_csv that has CAMPAIGN_ID and set of columns I need from df. I need to split df into one csv file for each campaign, that will have rows from that campaign and only those columns that are as per mapping_csv.
I am getting type error as below.
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
This is what I tried.

```
for campaign in df['CAMPAIGN_ID'].unique():
  df2 = df[df['CAMPAIGN_ID']==campaign]
  # remove blank columns
  df2.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
  for column in df2.columns:
    if df2[column].unique()[0]=="0000-00-00" and df2[column].unique().shape[0]==1:
      df2 = df2.drop(column, axis=1)
  for column in df2.columns:
    if df2[column].unique()[0]=='0' and df2[column].unique().shape[0]==1:
      df2 = df2.drop(column, axis=1)
  # select required columns
  df2 = df2[mapping_csv.loc[mapping_csv['CAMPAIGN_ID']==campaign, 'Variable_List'].str.replace(" ","").str.split(",")]
  file_shape = df2.shape[0]
  filename = "cart_"+str(dt.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'))+"_"+campaign+"_rowcnt_"+str(file_shape) 
  df2.to_csv(filename+".csv",index=False)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

This is how data looks like -
[image]

This is how mapping looks like -
[image]

Comment: add a minimal reproductible example of the dataframes please

Answer (score 0):

This addresses your core problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['foo','foo','bar','bar',],a=[1,2,3,4,], b=[5,6,7,8], c=[1,2,3,4]))
mapper = dict(foo=['a','b'], bar=['b','c'])

for each_id in df.id.unique():
    df_id = df.query(f'id.str.contains("{each_id}")').loc[:,mapper[each_id]]
    print(df_id)
```

Comment: This give me a different type error. unhasha ble type: 'Series'

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest simplifying your code to the bare minimum of what you are trying to do, using the framework provided above. Then post that minimal example so that it can be evaluated, and not guessed at.